# Can't bind to 'matDatepicker' since it isn't a known property of 'input' - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have just copied and pasted angular material code for datePicker and input, but I am getting this error for the datePicker.

`app.module`

```js
import {MaterialModule} from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
imports: [
...
MaterialModule
]
```

```html
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Rechercher" [(ngModel)]="filterHistorique">
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
    <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

This is the error I am having in my browser:

> Can't bind to 'mdDatepicker' since it isn't a known property of
>   'input' If 'md-datepicker' is an Angular component, then verify that
>   it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'md-datepicker' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message. (" [ERROR
>   ->]

The error is for the datepicker, when I removed it, the errors disappears

Comment: You added the MaterialModule, but you have to add all the modules you use too. In this case, it's `MdInput` and `MdDatePicker`.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

While using `mat-datepicker`, you have to import `MatDatepickerModule` as well, also `MatNativeDateModule` is recommended to be imported too. see docs **[here](https://material.angular.io/components/component/datepicker)**.

```
import { MaterialModule, MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    MaterialModule,            // <----- this module will be deprecated in the future version.
    MatDatepickerModule,        // <----- import(must)
    MatNativeDateModule,        // <----- import for date formating(optional)
    MatMomentDateModule         // <----- import for date formating adapted to more locales(optional)
  ]
```

For optional module of date formating, see **[Module for DateAdapter](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/datepicker/datepicker.md#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings)** from material team.

**Mention**: please avoid using `MaterialModule` for it'll be deprecated in the future.

Comment: I need to update my @angular/material module to the latest version for currently, my IDE doesn't find `MdDatePickerModule` when I import it. I guess, once it will be done, my problem will be solved

Comment: @edkeveked ok, maybe you will need to update all `@angular/xxx` packages as well based on the latest `@angular/material`(I have done this thing before). good luck.

Comment: This isn't working for me... Even though `MdDatepickerModule` is in the `app.module`, the error persists.

Comment: @NateGardner where are you using `mdDatePicker`? is this used at **submodule**?

Comment: @Pengyy, this worked really well for me, thanks.  FYI, I didn't need MaterialModule.

Comment: @RobertBernstein the `MaterialModule` will be deprecated in the future version, better to not use it any more. I have add some comments in my answer.

Comment: `MdDatePickerModule` has been renamed to `MatDatepickerModule`

Comment: Also make sure you're adding `[matDatepicker]`, not `[matDatePicker]`. Don't ask me how I know this.

Comment: Thanks @pengyy, importing this optional module also helps with this [annoying no-error-logged mat-datepicker bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388827/mat-datepicker-makes-the-app-crash-without-logged-error/52389888).

Answer (score 7):

you need to import `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` if you used NgModule and formgroup. so your app.module should be like that

```
import {MaterialModule} from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MdDatepickerModule,        
    MdNativeDateModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
```

**Note: MaterialModule Removed. please use separate module instead. *like MdDatepickerModule*** see here https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta11-carapace-parapet-2017-09-21

Answer (score 7):

To use `MatDatePicker` in application add the following lines in your **app.module.ts** (`or the current module your component/page belongs to`) file:

1. import  `MatDatepickerModule`, `MatNativeDateModule` in your app.module.ts.

```
import { MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
```

> for angular 10.x import them independently
>
> ```
> import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
> import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
> ```

2. Add `MatDatepickerModule`, `MatNativeDateModule` under @NgModule in **imports** and **exports**' array:

```
@NgModule ({
           imports: [
               MatDatepickerModule,
               MatNativeDateModule 
           ],
           exports: [
               MatDatepickerModule, 
               MatNativeDateModule 
           ]
       })
```

Comment: why to add in exports array ? @vaishali chaudhari is it when you have created a seperated module and you try to export all mat module from that shared module?

Answer (score 5):

In the latest versions of Angular Material, you have to import `MatDatepickerModule` from `@angular/material/datepicker` in this case and `MatNativeDateModule` from `@angular/material/core`.

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';

 @NgModule ({
   imports: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule
   ]
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to import below module

```js
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';

@NgModule ({
  imports: [
    MatDatepickerModule
   ]
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Below import works for me my on my solution in Angular8

```
@NgModule ({
        imports: [
            MatDatepickerModule,
            MatNativeDateModule,
        ]
 });
```