# Can't bind to 'mdDatepicker' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to make use of Angular Material design, but I keep running into this error

`Can't bind to 'mdDatepicker' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.`

I'm following [this documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) to install MD.

I have imported the following into my app.module.ts

```ts
/* Material Design */
import { MdDatepickerModule, MdNativeDateModule } from "@angular/material";
```

and added it to `@NgModule`

```ts
@NgModule({
    imports:
    [
        ...
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpModule,
        /* Material Design */
        MdDatepickerModule,
        MdNativeDateModule,
    ],
```

In my component template I just copy pasted the example's code

```ts
<md-form-field>
    <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
    <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
    <md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
</md-form-field>
```

I don't do anything special in my component.ts file

```ts
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { TranslationPipe } from "../../../pipes";

@Component({
    selector: "date-picker",
    templateUrl: "./date-picker.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./date-picker.component.scss"],
})
export class DatePickerComponent {

    @Input()
    date;

    constructor(
        private translationPipe: TranslationPipe,
    ) {

    }
}
```

I'm stuck here and I can't find any solutions to this. The only solution I found was [Can't bind to 'mdDatepicker' since it isn't a known property of 'input' - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584323/cant-bind-to-mddatepicker-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input-angula) but as you can see I implemented it and it didn't help me.

I guessing I'm looking over something, or did I miss a step?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `DatePickerComponent` part of the same `NgModule` as the imports shown above?

Comment: It's component of my `shared.module.ts`, which is imported in my `app.module.ts`. The shown code is from `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directives need to be listed in `imports: [...]` of the module where they are used.

```ts
@NgModule({
    imports:
    [
      MdDatepickerModule,
      MdNativeDateModule, 
    ]
}
export class SharedModule {
```

Importing them in `AppModule` only makes them available in components listed in `directives: [...]` of `AppModule` but nowhere else.

Comment: aah, I thought `app.module.ts` was like a global thing. You fixed it! thanks.

Comment: Service provided on `AppModule` become available everywhere (global singleton), but directives, components, and pipes need to be imported in every module individually to make them available.

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of angular4 datepicker, the syntax was changed to the below code:

Starting of DatePicker Module:

```
<mat-input-container>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose A Date:"><br/><br/>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
</mat-input-container>
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

This worked for me and was able to see the output in the UI.