# mat-datepicker makes the app crash without logged error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I've got this page component template at the url `/demo`

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Choose a date">
</mat-form-field>
```

Which renders fine, but as soon as I rewrite this as

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

the app redirects to the url `/` and does not displays anything but blank space. Nothing is logged in the console.

The code is supposed to work because it's copied from Angular Material [basic datepicker example](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples). I've imported `MatFormFieldModule`, `MatInputModule` and `MatDatepickerModule`.

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to additionally import the optional Material module `MatNativeDateModule`. No dependency is explicitly stated in Material's doc on `mat-datepicker`, but it seems to be required in some cases.

Thanks to [@pengyy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7579471/pengyy) 's answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584323/cant-bind-to-matdatepicker-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input-angul/44584399#44584399) that helped me get to this solution.

Comment: Worth noting that they recommend using the `MatMomentDateModule` for better locale support. See documentation here: 
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/datepicker/datepicker.md#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody still encounters this problem, even after the solution of Nino Filiu, try to add the MatDatePickerModule dependency in the app.module.ts.

I had a lazy loaded module, containing mat-dialogs where the mat-datepicker was used.
I initially had my mat dependencies within the lazy loaded module. Only after moving MatDatePickerModule to the app.module.ts, the view (dialog) stopped crashing.